# Poisson distribution - test per patient

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

In a positive tailed distribution (i.e. Poisson/ exponential shape), the probability a patient can have $3$ tests is $0.9$, where the chance of using $4$ tests per patient is $0.05$, $5$ tests $=0.03$ and $6$ tests $=0.02$ [these are manually input with no formula, based on empirical knowledge]. What formula can I use to get these probabilities?